# Can showing a popup with my other site when users perform a search give me Google penalty?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, pagerank

I have photos search engine. I want promote my other page with funny videos (completly other content) on my photos search engine.

When user writes something in search input and then clicks on search button I want in new window open my other page which I want to promote.

Can this can give me Google penalty? I hear Googlebot does not love popups.

Comment: I assume that your photo search engine is not crawlable and not indexable by Google at all, right?   Because Google doesn't like to index search results.   They consider it bad user experience.  Having your search engine results show up in Google's search results could trigger a penalty of its own.  See [Matt Cutts: Search results in search results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no my search results is not indexed, i only want open popup new window when user click on search button i will show normal search results but in new window will open new page which i want to promote, this can give me some google penalty?